# Is there any way to extract song's info (artist and track name) from the iTunes window

Tags: c#, winapi

Is there any way to extract song's info (artist and track name) from the iTunes window?

[image]

If I just send `WM_GETTEXT` message to the specified window it gives me "LCD section" text every time:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int Param, System.Text.StringBuilder text);

const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x0D;

// ...

System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(255);
int res = SendMessage((IntPtr)0x00030516, WM_GETTEXT, sb.Capacity, sb); // sb contains "LCD section" atm
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your actual goal here

Comment: iTunes draws its own UI, the song details are not part of the "real" window title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple provides a COM interface for accessing iTunes. You can download the headers from [Apple's Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/). They are available with a free account (Apple ID), and are called "iTunes COM for Windows SDK". Use this instead.

The method you want appears to be `IiTunes::get_CurrentTrack()`. [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2004/05/08/128645.aspx) has more information (on the managed code side, but the idea is the same).